# Xcode : Can't Export in-house app .. provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ad-hoc-distribution, in-house-distribution

I'm trying to distribute my app as a `in-house` app.. But i'm having this error :

> Your account does not have permission to create iOS In House
>   provisioning profiles.

These are the steps i'm following :

[image]

---

My account (Entity) type is **Company / Organization**

[image]

---

Even when I try to create provisioning profile manually from the developer portal.. I don't have any choice called `in-house`

[image]

Also created **Ad-Hoc provisioning profile** but it didn't help me here

Any idea how to fix this error?

And thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To use **In House** or **Enterprise** method of distribution you have to be enrolled in [Apple Developer Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/). Your screenshot of the Membership page says **Apple Developer Program**, means you cannot use the **In House** method of distribution with this development team.

Comment: I am in a similar predicament, where my membership is **Apple Developer Program**, but the error I get when I try to Distribute is `Profile is not an "iOS In House" profile.` I thought that meant I need to choose "In House" from under the "Distribution" headline in order to get the right kind of profile, but it looks like I do not have access to do so.